# Vertical rhythm in Chrome and IE9

Tags: css

I was working on vertical rhythm of my css framework - it looks perfect in firefox but different in chrome and ie9. Anyone know what the cause?

my framework typography page:
http://kenhty.github.com/Natural/typography.htm

Comment: I see no difference in all three browsers

Comment: I assume he means this page : http://kenhty.github.com/Natural/grid.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the box-flex grid, then check out the specs of the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) on using flexible box. There are a couple issues you're running into...

For one, support is extremely limited. Firefox 18+, Chrome 21+, no support in IE and Safari. As such, you are experiencing issues in Chrome because production Chrome is the only one that actually supports your code, and also you are missing the following styling:

`-webkit-flex-direction: column`

Yours is defaulting to `row`, which is causing your issues in Chrome.

More perplexing is that I'm on Firefox 15 and it's displaying your Grid properly... Yet when viewing the computer styles, it doesn't even display your grid styling, as Firefox 15 doesn't yet support it. So I'm actually amazed that you're grid displays properly in Firefox.

Anyway, check out what browsers support it and make sure you are overriding any default settings that need to be overridden.